# How to use wslite.rest.RestClient to get simple boolean value

Tags: json, rest, groovy

I have a problem when using wslite.rest.RestClient in groovy, when I want to get response from endpoint that returns simple boolean "false".

```
def client = new wslite.rest.RESTClient("url:port")
def booleanResponse = client.get(path: "/path")
```

I get this error:

```
wslite.rest.RESTContentParseException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Endpoint that is returning boolean (in spring-boot) looks like this:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/path", produces = HAL_JSON_VALUE)
public boolean endpointName(@PathVariable("param") String param) {
return false;
}
```

Is there any posibility to get this value without editing endpoint? I want to use RestClient in tests only.

I tried adding some extra properties like

```
accept: ContentType.TEXT
```

but it of course doesn't work (it returns 406 Not acceptable response).